# Python - How to improve weave function and add a function to class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code to weave the split_input `['5,4 4,5 8,7', '6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3', '7,6', '9,8', '5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4']` together. However I feel like this can be done more efficient (especially the weave function) but I have no clue how to improve it without importing any modules.

I also wanted to add the get_route function in my class but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. The error I got was `TypeError: unbound method get_route() must be called with Class1 instance as first argument (got list instance instead)`

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.row = row

    def append(self, coordinate):
        self.row += [coordinate]

    def extend(self, row):
        for coordinate in row:
            self.row += [coordinate]

    def weave(self, row2):
        result = Class1([])
        for i in range(len(self.row)):
            if i < len(self.row):
                result.append(self.row[i])
            if i < len(row2.row):
                result.append(row2.row[i])
        if len(row2.row) > len(self.row):
            result.extend(row2.row[len(self.row):])
        return result

def get_route(split_input):
    rows = []
    for i in range(len(split_input)):
        rows += [Class1(split_input[i].split())]
    previous_row = rows[0]

    for row in rows[1:]:
        previous_row = previous_row.weave(row)
    return previous_row


woven_rows = get_route(split_input)
print woven_rows
```

Do you have any good advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what the expected result is.

Comment: The output is a list with all the lists from the input weaved together. First, the first and the second list are weaved. Then the third row is weaved trough the previous list etc.

Comment: How about providing the result for your example? That would really help understanding what is required.

Comment: The result would be 5,4 5,5 9,8 7,8 7,6 6,5 6,3 6,4 4,5 3,2 8,7 9,6 4,3

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite easy if you could import a few functions from the standard library and have a better formatted input.

```
input = [(1.2, 2.3), (4.5,), (6.7, 8.9), ...]
res = reduce(lambda i, j: [e  for t in zip_longest(i, j) for e in t if e], input)
```

If you can't have the standard library functions, you can use the following equivalents and a bit of fiddling with strings gives the correct result.

```
def zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None):
    # zip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    num_active = len(iterators)
    if not num_active:
        return
    while True:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                num_active -= 1
                if not num_active:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)

def repeat(object, times=None):
    # repeat(10, 3) --> 10 10 10
    if times is None:
        while True:
            yield object
    else:
        for i in range(times):
            yield object

def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value


a = ['5,4 4,5 8,7', '6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3', '7,6', '9,8', '5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4']

b = [eval('(' + s.replace(',','.').replace(' ', ',') + ',)') for s in a]

c = reduce(lambda i, j: [e  for l in zip_longest(i, j) for e in l if e], b)

d = ' '.join(str(a).replace('.', ',') for a in c)
```